# Is there a way to wait for boot to complete

Tags: systemd, startup

With `systemd` one can query if the boot has completed by the command

```
systemctl is-system-running
```

which returns error code if boot hasn't completed. If one want to wait for the boot to complete one can of course rerun the command until it returns `0`.

I think there "must be a better way" to do this. Is there a method that doesn't rely on polling?

The reason I want to do this is that I currently have a script that downloads firmware to a device that is then rebooted and want to monitor it to see if it boots cleanly. I currently do this by issuing `systemctl is-system-running` via SSH until it returns `0` or it doesn't within the time the boot ought to have completed. Of course I want this to finish as soon as possible.

Comment: Of course. Write a service that requires the system to finish starting.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was thinking of a doing this in a script.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It would be nice to mention exactly what you think is unclear in the question so I can improve it. (I think it's quite clear myself)

Comment: That wasn't my close reason, but okay.

Comment: @skyking Just update it to say you want a command that will wait until boot completes... BTW, [PR #9796](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9796) was just accepted in systemd, so starting with systemd v240 it will be possible to do so with `systemctl is-system-running --wait`. :-D

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to wait for this condition without polling this command on a loop, but unfortunately it's not that straightforward...

systemd will post a [StartupFinished signal](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/#Manager-StartupFinished) on D-Bus once the boot is complete, so it is possible to watch for that and get a notification for it.

Here is a [simple `dbus-wait` tool](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/dbus-wait) that can watch for signals on D-Bus.

I managed to wait until startup was completed by using this command:

```
dbus-wait org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager StartupFinished
```

The problem with this approach is that there's a race condition there. If first I check whether the system is running (with `systemctl is-system-running`) and see that it's still "starting" and then decide to wait for the signal, it's possible that by the time `dbus-wait` will connect to the bus and start waiting for the signal, that systemd just finished startup and already posted this signal in the bus, which will make `dbus-wait` wait for an event that won't happen and eventually time out...

On the other hand, it should be possible to implement this in a way that is free from race conditions, by first registering the watch for the event, then checking the property and if it's still not set to "running" then run the event loop to wait for the signal.

I implemented the approach above and proposed it to upstream systemd. My suggestion is to allow running `systemctl is-system-running --wait` for this purpose (but it is possible this might end up making it to systemd with a different syntax, possibly a separate command.) The proposal for the new systemd feature can be found at [PR #9796](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9796) on systemd project. (I'll update this answer once it's accepted and merged.)

---

**UPDATE**: [PR #9796](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9796) was just merged into systemd, so starting with systemd v240, it will be possible to wait until boot is completed with the following command:

```
systemctl is-system-running --wait
```

Comment: The thing with `systemctl is-system-running --wait` is that `dbus` might not be running yet. I need to execute `systemctl list-units` in a LXC container (using `lxc-attach`) after starting it. Both `list-units` and `is-system-running` say "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory" at first. In this case I see no better option than: `while ! systemctl is-system-running --wait; do sleep 1; done`.

Comment: @x-yuri: You comment is spot on, this race condition completely undermines the usefulness of ``is-system-running``. Unfortunately, your loop-based solution is incomplete as well: if the system never enters the ``running`` state but immediately transitions to say ``degraded``, it will never terminate.

Comment: The first proposal is super racy, it's dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

#### Waiting Unit file

Here's a prototype that does what your looking for. To start here's a systemd unit file, `waity.service`:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/waity.service
[Unit]
Description=Waity Service
After=systend-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/bin/waity.sh
```

#### Waiting Script

It runs a script which does the interrogating of systemd to see if it's finished booting:

```
$ cat /opt/bin/waity.sh
#!/bin/bash

while $(sleep 10); do
  echo "waiting for systemd to finish booting..."
  if systemctl is-system-running | grep -qE "running|degraded"; then
    break
  fi
done

echo "systemd finished booting..."
echo "...do something else..."
```

#### Example run

Now enable this service:

```
$ systemctl enable --now waity.service
```

Now when we start up our system this service will sit in a 10 second loop until it sees that the `is-system-running` action of `systemctl` returns either a `running` or `degraded` state. Either of these is an indication that the system has completed booting.

The status of this service:

```
$ systemctl status waity.service
● waity.service - Waity Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/waity.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: systemd finished booting...
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: ...do something else...
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 systemd[1]: Child 4519 belongs to waity.service
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 systemd[1]: waity.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 systemd[1]: waity.service changed running -> dead
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 systemd[1]: waity.service: cgroup is empty
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 systemd[1]: Collecting waity.service
Aug 03 22:07:17 centos7 systemd[1]: Collecting waity.service
```

We can see in the above messages that we've detected a completed boot:

```
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: systemd finished booting...
Aug 03 22:06:01 centos7 waity.sh[4519]: ...do something else...
```

At which point we could do the `...do something else...`. Once this is all complete this service will go to a done/dead state.

Comment: This is a very complete answer and it seems to do exactly what the OP asked for, since it removes the need to externally poll the system. I wonder if there's a solution without busy waiting as well, as one would do asynchronously with callbacks or promises in JavaScript.

Comment: @TelmoTrooper - I saw none, but that doesn't mean there aren't. Given this is running just during a boot, it runs every 10 seconds, and then once the boot is complete it stops, this will run at most maybe a half dozen times, seems reasonable to me, IMO.

Comment: Sim doesn't this have the same drawback as my original solution? Namely that it will be between 0 and 10s late due to the polling loop? That's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @skyking - there's a race condition in the other approach using D-Bus, you can't escape it, hence why I did a simple polling solution here, to be able to gain access to the `is-system-running` action of `systemctl`. The amount of time can be controlled with this approach by making a tighter loop. I see no other method beyond this here.